# JavaScript POST request to Golang server error - Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, go, post, async-await, fetch

I am making a POST request in JavaScript to my Go server to POST some JSON data. The backend recieves the data succesfully. 
If I console log the result of the promise I get **Unexpected end of JSON input** error  at line where **fetchResponse.json()** is called. I cant figure out why it is happening.

**JavaScript**

```
const sendScore = async () => {

    try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/sendscore`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({name:"kris"})
        });

        const data = await fetchResponse.json();
        return data;

    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}

const sendScoreBtn = document.querySelector("#sendScoreBtn");
sendScoreBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Sending score...")
    const res = sendScore()
    res.then(console.log)

})
```

**Go** /sendscore endpoint handler

```
func recieveScore(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var res playerScore
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&res); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Line 31", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Res", res)
}

func main() {

    // Serve static files(js, css)
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/sendscore", recieveScore)

    fmt.Println("Server started. Listening on port :8000")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil))
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with `w`, the response writer. Where are you sending the JSON response that the request is expecting?

Comment: @Quentin I am sending the score to my backend and then decoding it to a variable

Comment: Yes, I can see what you are doing with the data from the **request**. I asked about sending the **response**.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. It seems I dont understand the process at all.

Comment: The browser makes a request to the server. The server reads the request and determines what response to send back to the browser. I can't see the code which determines what the response should be or which sends it back to the server.

Comment: Maybe you should be reading an introductory tutorial for whatever Go framework you are using to write the web service instead of resorting to an SO question.

Comment: @Quentin I am not using any Go framework. I understand that my JavaScript POST request sends data to backend and that I will handle that there.

Comment: "I am not using any Go framework" — Something has to be calling your function and passing values to `w` and `r`

Comment: "I understand that my JavaScript POST request sends data to backend" — Yes

Comment: "and that I will handle that there" — And you seem to be only half handling it

Comment: @Quentin I think I got some insight from my schoolmate. I think the problem was I didnt write anything to response in backend so it left that unhandled. The case is I actually dont want that JSON back I sent. I only want to send it to backend and I am only interested that the POST request was succesful.

Comment: You must send a response. If you don't want to send JSON back then don't send JSON back but you need to send something even if it a 204 status (but then change the client-side code so it doesn't try to parse the response as JSON).

Comment: @Quentin Well If I have to send then I dont have any other idea other than the JSON that was sent?

Comment: *gestures to his previous comment where he mentioned a 204 status*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not sending response back to the browser and therefore it couldnt parse any JSON.
Updated Go handler, which made the process work.

```
func recieveScore(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var res playerScore
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&res); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Line 31", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Res", res)
    
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(res) // Writing the result to response
}
```